# Can a probability generating function fail to be analytic on any neighborhood of 1?

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory, continuity, generating-functions, moment-generating-functions

Any [probability generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) $G(z)$ is analytic on at least the open unit disk of the complex plane, because its Taylor series expansion about $z=0$ has a radius of convergence of at least 1. Moreover, any PGF satisfies $G(1)=1$, so the Taylor series converges at that point.

But I don't know of any theorem that says that any PGF must be analytic in a neighborhood of $z=1$, or even that derivatives $G^{(n)}(1)$ must exist at $z=1$. In order to calculate the random variable's factorial moments, strictly speaking we must instead take the more cumbersome limit $\lim \limits_{z \to 1^-} G^{(n)}(z)$, which is guaranteed to exist by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem).

Are there actually examples of PGFs that are not analytic on any neighborhood of $z=1$? (This could only happen if the PGF's radius of convergence equals 1.) The Wikipedia article on Abel's theorem linked above does give an example of a function
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{3^n}-z^{2 \cdot 3^n}}{n}$$
that is analytic on the open unit disk, and defined at $z=1$ but discontinuous there, so that no derivatives $f^{(n)}(1)$ exist for any positive $n$. But this function is not a probability generating function. Are there probability functions that are similarly pathological near $z=1$, so that we really do need to use Abel's theorem instead of just directly taking derivatives at $z=1$?

Comment: There are equivalent definitions of analytic functions based on power series. Look up [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Relationship_to_analyticity).

Comment: @TravorLZH The issue is that the PGF is defined as a power series about $z=0$, but my question is whether we can Taylor expand the PGF about the different point $z = 1$.

Comment: What about a distribution engineered to decay so slowly that it has no moments, e.g. $p_n = \log 2 \cdot \left( \frac{1}{\log n} - \frac{1}{\log(n+1)}\right)$, $n=2,3,4,\dots$?  Then $G(z) = \sum_{n=2}^\infty z^n p_n$ should diverge for all $z > 1$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Excellent suggestion, feel free to post as an answer. Do you know whether all of the derivatives of that $G(z)$ diverge as $z \to 1^-$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Just out of curiosity, your proposed $G(z)$ appears to have a finite value of about 0.2814 (or 0.4060 if you get rid of the factor of $\log(2)$) at $z = -1$ - do you know if there's an analytic expression for the sum of that alternating series?

Comment: As to an analytic expression, I don't know, and neither does Mathematica.

Comment: I'd have to think a bit to prove that this $G(z)$ actually does diverge for $z > 1$, so I'll hold off posting as an answer for now.  Feel free to post one yourself if you like.

Comment: I think the derivatives must diverge.  For positive real $z$, everything in sight is positive, and so as $z \uparrow 1$, by monotone convergence $G'(z)$ should approach $\sum n p_n = \infty$.

Comment: the standard example here is $p_0 = 0$, $p_1=0$ and $p_k=\frac{1}{k(k-1)}$ for $k\in \big\{2,3,4,\dots\big\}$.